# laravel 4 many to many relationship integration test not passing

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Every entity is being saved and has an ai id. Only the test on line 34 is not passing.

```
<?php
class AssignmentTest extends TestCase
{
    protected $assignment;

    public function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();
        $this->assignment = new Assignment;
    }

    public function testAssignmentAssociations()
    {
        $facility = Facility::create(array(
        'name' => 'test facility',
        'code' => 'test-facility'
        ));

        $user = new User;
        $user->id = 1;

        $shift = Shift::create(array(
        'name' => 'test shift',
        'start_time' => 0,
        'end_time' => 600
        ));

        $this->assignment->facilities()->save($facility);
        $this->assignment->shift()->associate($shift);
        $this->assignment->user()->associate($user);
        $this->assignment->save();

        $this->assertEquals(1, $facility->id);
        $this->assertEquals(1, $this->assignment->facilities()->count());
        $this->assertEquals(1, $this->assignment->shift_id);
        $this->assertEquals(1, $this->assignment->user_id);
    }
}

// Facility model
public function assignments()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Assignment', 'assignment_facilities');
}

// Assignment model
public function facilities()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Facility', 'assignment_facilities');
}
```

#### Edit

Apparently removing this line will make the test successful. Now I'm interested as to why when saving the assignment the association will no longer return a successful count?

```
<?php
$this->assignment->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

I havent tested - but dont you need to 'save' the shift and user records themselves, before you try and associate them against the assignment?

```
    $user = new User;
    $user->id = 1;

    $shift = Shift::create(array(
    'name' => 'test shift',
    'start_time' => 0,
    'end_time' => 600
    ));
    $shift->id = 1;


    $this->assignment->facilities()->save($facility);
    $this->assignment->shift()->save($shift);
    $this->assignment->user()->save($user);
    $this->assignment->shift()->associate($shift);
    $this->assignment->user()->associate($user);
    $this->assignment->save();
```